# How to compute group cohomology $H^2_\sigma(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ with nontrivial $G$-module

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, gap

How to compute group cohomology $H^2_\sigma(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ with nontrivial group action $\sigma$.

$$\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}= \langle a,b| a b =ba\rangle$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2= \langle c,d| c^2=1=d^2,c d =dc\rangle$$

If I require the group action is $\sigma(a): c\rightarrow d$, $\sigma(a): d\rightarrow c$, $\sigma(b): c\rightarrow d$, $\sigma(b): d\rightarrow c$

My questions:

1. how to compute group cohomology $H^2_\sigma(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2)$?
2. What's the group  $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes_\sigma (\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} )$ ?

Comment: At least the basic system will not do this for the infinite group $\Z\times\Z$. If your factor group is finite and solvable, the manual chapter on 2-Cohomology and Extensions https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap46.html#X877AAB887D4507E3 describes the functions. Before trying to generalize to the infinite case (which in theory is not that different) I suggest you get comfortable with the finite case first (say through the examples in the manual section), as the syntax and objects can be confusing.

Comment: I'm just commenting to link your other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2575990/7719

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve these two questions using the `polycyclic` package, which comes bundled with GAP. There are multiple ways to input the enter the problem into GAP. I'll choose one via matrix modules: The group $G := \mathbb{Z}^2$ with generators $a,b$ is acting here on the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2$ (with basis $c,d$), with both generators of $G$ acting via the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. So:

```
gap> LoadPackage("polycyclic");
true
gap> G:=AbelianPcpGroup([0,0]);
Pcp-group with orders [ 0, 0 ]
gap> m:=[[0,1],[1,0]]*Z(2);;
gap> cr:=CRRecordByMats(G,[m,m]);;
gap> h2:=TwoCohomologyCR(cr);;
```

Unfortunately, $h2$ is not a nice group object; one has to read the documentation of `TwoCohomologyCR` to learn how to interpret its output. Here, we are interested in `h2.factor`, which is:

```
gap> h2.factor;
rec( denom := [ <a GF2 vector of length 4> ],
  gens := [ [ Z(2)^0 ] ],
  imgs := [ [ Z(2)^0 ], [ Z(2)^0 ] ],
  prei := [ <an immutable GF2 vector of length 4> ].
  rels := [ 2 ] )
```

This output means that the second cohomology group has one generator (in `gens`), with relative order 2 -- i.e. it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

To get the corresponding extensions, use $ExtensionClassesCR$:

```
gap> exts:=ExtensionClassesCR(cr);
[ Pcp-group with orders [ 0, 0, 2, 2 ],
  Pcp-group with orders [ 0, 0, 2, 2 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's reasonable to do this by hand. The following is analogous to the computation of group cohomology for the group $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $A := \mathbb{Z}[t_{1}^{\pm},t_{2}^{\pm}]$ be the group ring of the group $G := \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Then the $A$-module $\mathbb{Z} \simeq A/(t_{1}-1,t_{2}-1)A$ has an $A$-module resolution $$ \dotsb \to 0 \to A e_{2,1} \stackrel{f_{2}}{\to} A e_{1,1} \oplus A e_{1,2} \stackrel{f_{1}}{\to} A e_{0,1} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$ where $f_{2}(e_{2,1}) = (t_{2}-1)e_{1,1} - (t_{1}-1)e_{1,2}$ and $f_{1}(e_{1,i}) = (t_{i}-1)e_{0,1}$ for $i=1,2$. Let $$ M := \mathbb{Z}/(2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(2) $$ be the $A$-module as above. Applying $\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(-,M)$ to the above resolution gives a complex $$ M \stackrel{f_{1}^{\ast}}{\to} M^{\oplus 2} \stackrel{f_{2}^{\ast}}{\to} M \to 0 \to \dotsb $$ of $A$-modules, and taking cohomology at the $i$th cohomological degree gives $\mathrm{H}^{i}(G,M)$. In particular we have $$ \mathrm{H}^{2}(G, M) \simeq \operatorname{coker}(M^{\oplus 2} \stackrel{f_{2}^{\ast}}{\to} M) $$ where the map $f_{2}^{\ast} : M^{\oplus 2} \to M$ sends $(m_{1},m_{2}) \mapsto (t_{2}-1)m_{1} - (t_{1}-1)m_{2}$. Say $m_{i} \in M$ is of the form $(n_{i,1},n_{i,2})$ with $n_{i,\ell} \in \mathbb{Z}/(2)$. Then $\operatorname{im} f_{2}^{\ast}$ consists of the subgroup of $M$ generated by elements of the form $$ (n_{1,2}-n_{1,1} , n_{1,1}-n_{1,2}) - (n_{2,2}-n_{2,1} , n_{2,1}-n_{2,2}) $$ for $n_{i,\ell} \in \mathbb{Z}/(2) = \{0,1\}$, in other words $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

---

One can generalize this to compute group cohomology for the group $G = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n}$ for any positive integer $n$, the point being that $\{t_{1}-1 , \dotsc , t_{n}-1\}$ is a regular sequence on $A := \mathbb{Z}[t_{1}^{\pm} , \dotsc , t_{n}^{\pm}]$ so that the Koszul complex gives a resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ by free $A$-modules as above.

Comment: Stumbled across this and was slightly confused. What are the $e_{i, j}$? Are they the "generating elements" for $\mathbb{Z} \left[t^{\pm 1}, s^{\pm 1} \right]$? And so it suffices to specify the maps on those elements?

Comment: @m1820 They are the generators for the free modules, e.g. "$A e_{1,1} \oplus A e_{1,2}$" is a free $A$-module of rank $2$, and I have chosen an $A$-basis $\{e_{1,1},e_{1,2}\}$. Sorry for not being clear.